# MySQL multiple join issue when finding several username using different fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I am trying to accomplish is find several peoples usernames from an ID. The idea being not having to send multiple queries since I would like to find the username from several fields in the same table row.

So what I usually sent is something like the following.

```
Select username FROM users where ID =10.
Select username FROM users where currentUser =15
Select username FROM users where previousUser =2.
```

What I would like to do is something like the following which is written in english not a query

```
SELECT username1, username2, username3 from users 
currenttable.ID = users.ID creates username1
currenttable.currentID = users.ID  creates username2
currenttable.previousID = users.ID  creates username2
```

Comment: Do you mean you need 3 usernames in the same result-row or you need a result (even if it contains 3 rows) but obtain with a single SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MySQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to get all 3 results in a single row

```
SELECT username as username1 FROM users WHERE id = 1 
UNION
SELECT username as username2 FROM users WHERE id = 2 
UNION
SELECT username as username3 FROM users WHERE id = 3
```

or as @Bernd Buffen already answered, you can use a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: I went with the UNION solution, this worked better for me understanding how it worked vs the left join method. I think it solves the issue of matching several values in one row and query to one field in anohter table

Comment: Had to figure out how to accept it, I think the UNION is easier to understand for someone like me or others who want to do this. The ability to combine 4 queries into 1 X $x amount will save a ton of script time.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN is your friend. try something like this:

```
SELECT
 u1.username AS username1,
 u2.username as username2,
 u3.username AS username3
FROM users u1 
left join users u2 ON u2.currentID = u1.ID  
left join users u3 ON u3.previousID = u1.ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the question, but from what I've gathered, couldn't you just use a query like this:

```
SELECT username FROM users u WHERE u.ID = 10 OR u.currentUser = 15 OR u.previousUser = 2;
```